# Copying string containing hex 0x00 to the clipboard

Tags: java, string, byte, clipboard

I have an issue when copying a String containing the hex character 0x00 to the clipboard, and pasting it into an external application (hex editor, notepad++, etc). It terminates the String at the 0x00 byte.

When copying a String containing 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x02
It only pastes 0x01 0x02 0x03 into external applications.

Internally (within the same java program at least), it's fine, and I get the whole string back, e.g:

```
copying string
Str length = 7
Str hex = 01 02 03 00 01 02 03 
-----
Pasting string
Str length = 7
Str hex = 01 02 03 00 01 02 03
```

But after running this, pasting the clipboard to an external application will only copy the characters up to 0x00. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

source:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;

public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String strToCopy = new String(new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03});

    System.out.println("copying string");
    printStringDetails(strToCopy);
    copyStringToClipboard(strToCopy);

    System.out.println("-----");

    System.out.println("Pasting string");
    String pastedString = getStringFromClipboard();
    printStringDetails(pastedString);
}

public static void printStringDetails(String string)
{

    System.out.println(String.format("Str length = %d", string.length()));
    System.out.println(String.format("Str hex = %s", bytesToHex(string.getBytes())));
}

public static void copyStringToClipboard(String strToCopy)
{
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(strToCopy);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
}

public static String getStringFromClipboard()
{
    String returnedString = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    try
    {
        returnedString = (String)clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnedString;
}

/*
 * Converts bytes array to hex string
 */
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] byteArray)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : byteArray)
    {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ASCII `0x00` represents `NUL` .

From the following question at *superuser* dealing with this "character" : 
[Is there any way to copy null bytes (ASCII 0x00) to the clipboard on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/946533/is-there-any-way-to-copy-null-bytes-ascii-0x00-to-the-clipboard-on-windows):

> No, you cannot put text with embedded null characters on the
>   clipboard.

And

> A null character signals the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

In my laptop(OS X), everything goes okay if I paste the String to VIM.

[image]

Here is the hex info:

[image]

I think the problem depends on the implementation of the external application. If it could handle a 0x00, it will receive the whole string.

Comment: I'll try it on some other platforms.

I've "manually" copied the string from a C++ program to Notepad++ and it works, just not from Java to Notepad++, so I think it's a Java issue, but could be wrong